# R value of as.character(NA)

Tags: r, virtual-machine, na

Does anybody know the internal value of as.character(NA)? How would somebody represent an NA string on the interpreter level? In other words, how would someone who would like to implement an R VM do that?

I looked in the sourcecode of R but I could not find an self-explaining definition of NA_STRING, which seems to be the underlying representation of string value of NA.

Thank in advance for all sugestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `Rinternals.h`, `NA_STRING` is a `CHARSXP`, which is a "scalar string type (internal only)".